# how ot map multiple Hashicorp Vault policies to a GitHub team?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I associated the Vault policy `core` to the `default` and `root` GitHub teams according [to the Vault documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/github.html#configuration) as follows:

```
vault write auth/github/map/teams/default value=core
vault write auth/github/map/teams/root value=core
```

The members of the `root` team have additional permissions and I need each of them to be associated to both the `core` and `root` policies when they login with:

```
vault login -method=github token=20a2ab8ba7.....
```

Is there a way to map **both** the `root` and the `core` policies to the `root` GitHub team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/github/index.html#parameters-1):

value (string) - Comma separated list of policies to assign